# What is Angular JS vs Angular.io

Tags: angular

So I am trying, with some success to use the Angular File Manager (last commit in 2020, https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager).  I have one production release.  But I do not understand what the build function does in that project.  I use the source Javascript.  Then my boss sends me a link about the Angular Cache here, https://angular.io/cli/cache  And that does not even look like javascript.  I think that Angular JS is a javascript lib developed at google and now open source https://angularjs.org/  But what is angular.io?  And why does angular-filemanager need to build?

So can someone please help me understand how these two projects relate to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Angular Js was the frist version or angular which was launched by google its like any other js cdn like jquery

But after that google reworked on it and created angular ie angular.io which is a framework so you need to follow this for your filemanger and build it

Comment: Wierd....  ....I will read over Angular.io....  ....but can you tell me in general, how do you build javascript?  I thought that it was an interpreted language...  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: Actually building in javascript means minifying it

Comment: Ok then its not critical yes?   I need some general background on what that Angular.io really is....   ...seems weird, different than Angular JS.   Angular JS just moves data around an HTML page, just like DHTML.  But this Angular.io has @Component.  That looks more like Spring...   And it is built on Type Script not javascript, right?

Comment: Yes and typescript syntax also needs compilation to convert it into plain javascript